# SOUND OF HEAVEN

Tags: sound-design, worldizing, mixing, sound-effects

Hey guys. I am currently working on a film. Its still in its pre-production stage. There's a scene in which the protagonist is in an empty room, which HE thinks is HEAVEN. The script mentions that the room has a particular tone to it which is obviously diffrent from that in a normal room. The first sound that came to my head was a drone sound. I also tried layering the sound of the drone and the Didgeridoo and  play around with the pitch. Also tried worldizing it by taking it out in a large empty basement and re- record it to get the natural reverb to it.
So my question here is are there any more suggestions i could get from you all? May be some other approach i might use to get the right sound?
Thank You.

Answer (score 6):

This is a perfect opportunity to get inside your protagonists head and use sound to tell the story more effectively. I imagine we all have a different perception of what heaven sounds like...why not try to nail your protagonists POV. This was well done in the movie Contact for example.

My perception of the sound of heaven might include a collage of my favorite music, the sound of my wife's voice, the ambience from my favorite geographic spots on Earth, my mother singing etc..

Answer (score 5):

Since its something in his head, I would start by trying going in the completely other direction, then big.
You could try an approach with a deadening treatment to the voice and objects surrounding him. (Like how a voice sounds like in an anechoic chamber).

Sounds fun.

Best wishes,

Mikkel

Answer (score 3):

what does your character consider to be "heaven"?

Answer (score 2):

A good afterlife sound would be like the high-pitched, whining noise that you sometimes hear made by the plumbing in old houses, flophouse-type hotels etc.

Answer (score 0):

You mention that he "thinks" it's heaven. I haven't read the script, but if's its not, you could do a blend between reality and dream. Part beautiful, or what he'd think is heaven, with a hint of truth in the distance.

A fairly extreme TEST could be a large walk in refrigerator. One with a fairly quiet motor / AC, but with that cold 'wispy' air sound.. Pitch it up high and maybe dull the attack, with verb. This has made some interesting sounds for me personally.